# Would it be possible to use several replace arguments into one replace method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to delete some characters into a string (text with several words).

For this purpose I use the code below:

```
text2 = text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', '').replace('.', '').replace(':', '')
```

I have to add one replace method for each character to replace.

Is there any form to code in a smarter way? Something like this:

```
text2 = text.replace(',' '.' '\n' ':', '') # of course this is not working, just an example about how it could be.
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a regular expression.

Comment: Or list comprehension and a join: `text2 = ''.join(t for t in text if t not in ',\n.:')`

Comment: `str.translate` would be likely fastest for this case (single character replacements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `re.sub(r'[,.:\n]', '', text)`